# Second window in C++ OpenGL deactivates SOIL texture in first window

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, texture2d, soil

So I've been playing around with SOIL for openGL class, and I am having a weird problem with my project. I am to display two windows containing three viewports each, in which I draw a textured cube or ellipsoid in order to demonstrate my understanding of depth and face culling. Now the shapes all draw correctly, and when tested seperately it looks exactly as it is expected to, however as soon as I enable both windows at the same time, the texturing disables in window one. I have posted a similar question previously, so just to clarify, texturing works if i disable window two, or if I use the window one draw function in window two. It is only when both windows display at the same time that the problem comes up. I was also able to change the colour of the rendered shape, so my best thoughts are that I have somehow disabled the matrix or buffer holding textures in window one when I move to window two.

This is my main code w/ Initialisation
    void main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

```
    glutInitWindowSize(750, 250);

    #pragma region WINDOW ONE INITIALISATION
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 50);

    windowID[1] = glutCreateWindow("cubes");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-400, 400, -400, 400, -500, 500);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glutDisplayFunc(DrawWindowOne);
    #pragma endregion 

    #pragma region WINDOW TWO INITIALISATION
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 450);
    windowID[1] = glutCreateWindow("ellipsoids");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-60, 60, -60, 60, 60, 200);
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glutDisplayFunc(DrawWindowTwo);
    #pragma endregion

    LoadTextures(); // Handles the SOIL_load_OGL_Texture() lines. Works 100%

    gluQuadricTexture(quad, GL_TRUE);
}
```

and these are the two window draw functions

```
void DrawWindowOne()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

#pragma region Viewport One 

    glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250);                     

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);         

    DrawCubes();

#pragma endregion
#pragma region Viewport Two 

    glViewport(250, 0, 250, 250);   

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    DrawCubes();
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

#pragma endregion
#pragma region Viewport Three   

    glViewport(500, 0, 250, 250);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    DrawCubes();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

#pragma endregion

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void DrawWindowTwo()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     

    #pragma region Viewport One 

    glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    DrawEllipsoids();

    #pragma endregion
    #pragma region Viewport Two 

    glViewport(250, 0, 250, 250);   

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    DrawEllipsoids();
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    #pragma endregion
    #pragma region Viewport Three   

    glViewport(500, 0, 250, 250);   

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    DrawEllipsoids();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    #pragma endregion

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

This is a little bit of my object drawing code. I've stripped it down a fair bit; It only draws a single face for the cube (I've confirmed the same problem comes up if all viewports draw a single face).

```
void DrawCubes()
{
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); // front face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-a,-a,-a);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-a, a,-a);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f( a, a,-a);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f( a,-a,-a);
    glEnd()
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GLUT creates an OpenGL context *per window*. These context are not shared. In GL, at most one GL context can be "made current" to the thread, so any GL function you call will work with the currently active GL context.

If the code in your `WINDOW TWO INITIALISATION` is active, GLUT will create a new window and make its context current. As a consequence, your `LoadTextures()` call will affect only the second context, and your first context will not have any textures loaded.

One solution would be to call `LoadTextures()` twice. However, that function probably uses some variables to store the texture names - and those might not be identical between the two identical contexts, so conceptually, you would have to extend your code.

Another solution would be using *shared* contexts. These share any objects like Textures, Buffers, and so on. However, GLUT does not support that.

Yet another solution would be relying on freeglut's extensions over the "official" [GLUT specification](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html) (which is totally outdated in any case):

```
glutSetOption(GLUT_RENDERING_CONTEXT, GLUT_USE_CURRENT_CONTEXT);
```

will tell freeglut to not create a new context for the next window it creates, but re-use the existing one. Then, your code basically can work as you expect it to work.